# How to send in-app announcements to people using my iOS app?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have a couple apps on the Apple App Store and would like some way to send announcements to users whenever I want. Basically, I want to remotely change the text of an `IUAlertview` and only trigger it to appear if I want it to (upon app opening and only if I updated the message).

So far I have no problem making the `IUAlertview` appear on when the app opens, and I can easily program an `NSUserDefault` flag to only make the `IUAlertview` appear under certain circumstances, but really have no idea how to dynamically change the `UIAlertview` text without resubmitting my app to Apple continuously.

Can someone please explain how this is done? Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/notifications/

Comment: @Lirik - It is my understanding that local and push notifications are for apps that are either not running at all or running in the background... I just want to change some text on the first view after a user open the app

Comment: Push notifications will work either way. The way you handle it is the difference: If the app is closed or in background, it will be presented as a push notification, clicking it will open up the app. If the app is running, you will need to handle it and present an 'UIAlertView' displaying the text you want.

Comment: Push notifications is not what jake9115 has asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to have your app periodically (or upon each launch) check a file on a website that you control and if there is changed text (or a version number, or newer date than the last time an alert was displayed) there, then display that changed text in your UIAlertView.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the contribution. I thought of doing this, but had two questions. 1) Does apple allow dynamically changed text like this, since they would have a chance to "review" the message's contents? And two, do you have an example code snippet for how objective-c can check and parse the text of a URL?

Comment: No, Apple doesn't need to review the message's contents prior to you changing it.  And parsing can be as simple as "`messageToDisplay = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsFromURL: YOURURLHERE];`", however doing it this way means it's synchronous and may slow down your UI.  But it might be a good start.

Comment: Amazing, I had no idea it was that easy. I'm looking forward to trying this! Thanks.

Comment: It is that dead easy. And yes, Apple does allow that. Think of a messaging-app. Technically that is not much different from what messaging-apps do. They change the text of some UI elements dynamically based on data received from some server.

Comment: For your simple use case, don't hassle with version number. Fetch the header of that file first, where the change-date of the file is included. Compare that timestamp with the one that you stored last time when you displaed the message. Then fetch the full file only when the date of the file on the server is newer than the one you stored (if any).

Comment: This is exactly what I will do, thanks so much for the insight guys!